# Stop Command From Running in pre-invoke Hook - Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot, and I want a few checks to run before the Command is used. If one of these checks fail, I want the command to stop. I know I can use `client.before_invoke` to run the checks, but if I raise a custom error or use `return` the command invokes anyway. Is there a way to stop the command from invoking in the pre-invoke hook? The only way I can find to do it at the moment is by purposely raising a built-in error.